# Two columns don't stay in row (bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
        <section class="cards">
        <article class="card row no-gutters">
            <div class="userInfo col-3">
                <div class="user row">
                    <div class="img col-xl-4 col-md-12">
                        <img src="img/avatar.png">
                    </div>
                    <div class="about col-xl-7 col-md-12 pl-md-5">
                        <h6>Vardenis Pavardenis</h6>
                        <h6>Kebulo meistras</h6>
                        <h6>Petro servisas</h6>
                        <h6>Kaunas</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ratingsInfo col-5">
                <div class="rate">
                    <h6 id="ratings">Reitingas: </h6>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <small class="text-muted">(123)</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
    </section>
```

ratingsInfo should stay in the same row as userinfo but no it break into new row why?
I tried changing col-sizes col-xl and ... still doesnt do anything where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the article tag out and add the below css to your page.

```
.userInfo {float:left;}
.ratingsInfo {margin-left : 20px;float:left;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/javafiddleman/d19chtr6/7/

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Bootstrap, but the element div has the display: block; by default, that is what is making the break row, to change it you can add the style: "display: inline-block;" to both divs.

```
    <section class="cards">
    <article class="card row no-gutters">
        <div class="userInfo col-3">
            <div style="display: inline-block;" class="user row">
                <div class="img col-xl-4 col-md-12">
                    <img src="img/avatar.png">
                </div>
                <div class="about col-xl-7 col-md-12 pl-md-5">
                    <h6>Vardenis Pavardenis</h6>
                    <h6>Kebulo meistras</h6>
                    <h6>Petro servisas</h6>
                    <h6>Kaunas</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;" class="ratingsInfo col-5">
            <div class="rate">
                <h6 id="ratings">Reitingas: </h6>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                <small class="text-muted">(123)</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```